# Char Data type variables

Tags: c, arrays, variables, char

I'm studying a book called "Learn C on the Mac".  It defines the char data type as a 1 byte data type.  Does that mean that a variable with char data type can NOT hold an integer such as 5000?  I'm confused by this.  The book has an example program assigning a variable data type as char, with 5000 in the variable.  It is actually a string, 5000 long.  Example:  (char rating[5000];).  I thought char could only hold the ascii set or the numerical value?  Sorry I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: `char rating[5000]` creates an array with 5000 char elements.

Comment: If that book doesn't explain what arrays are, or got you sufficiently confused that you thought that statement somehow stored 5k in a char, please pick up another book, that one's not for you.

Comment: A single char can hold an integer value from -127 to +127. ( An unsigned char can hold 0 to 255. ) Ascii characters fall in the range of 0 to 127.

Comment: @CharlieBurns No. That's the **minimal** range. Nothing in the standard says that `char` can't be wider.

Comment: @CharlieBurns; I think rage is implementation defined. It can be altered (of course by hardware implementations).

Comment: I should have prepended my comment with "In general...."

Comment: @CharlieBurns; You missed that :)

Comment: Seriously, people, stop upvoting. **This is a very bad question.** IDK where you all upvoters put your sense of quality...

Comment: @H2CO3, I don't get it... Why did you answer then? I mean, simple questions from newbies may prompt very good answers. When I find one of those that rings my curiosity, usually I answer **and** upvote them.

Answer (score 5):

> Does that mean that a variable with char data type can NOT hold an integer such as 5000?

No. On a platform where a byte is extremely long, it is theoretically possible that `char` be able to hold the value `5000`.

---

**However, that has nothing to do with the example you read.** This:

```
char rating[5000];
```

creates an **array** of 5000 `char`s. **It is not initializing `rating` with the value `5000`.** Are you confusing this with the parentheses-initialization syntax of C++? That would be

```
char rating(5000);
```

and it does something entirely different. And it wouldn't be valid C at all anyway.

Comment: +1 Although you may mentioned what `char rating(5000);` means as you have mentioned it!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Thanks. I think that I mentioned that it's C++-style initialization.

Comment: Sorry I missed that! :)

Comment: I appreciate all answers to my question.  I think I now understand.  An Array of 5000 char is created, not necessarily a char variable holding the value 5000.  Thank you again.  Very Helpful.

Comment: @haccks:- The count moves on to 3 ;)

Answer (score 3):

`char rating[5000]` means *an array of `5000` characters*. That is, it will occupy an space of `5000 * sizeof(char)` in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

`char rating[5000]` will create an array with 5000 char elements.

Answer (score -1):

> the char data type as a 1 byte data type. Does that mean that a variable with char data type can NOT hold an integer such as 5000?

**Char** refers to *character*. As you already know, a `char` variable holds a space of 1 byte. It can, therefore, hold **exactly** *one* digit or *one* letter—no more, no less. **`Char` values are one-character values.**

So that means—a variable with char data type *cannot* hold an integer such as 5000. There isn't enough space for it on the computer memory. If you input a value with more than one character (e.g. `5000`), only the first character will be accepted. You cannot feed such data to a `char` variable.

---

Use this program to better your understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char s;
    scanf("%c", &s);
    printf("%c", s);
    return (0);   
}
```

Try inputting 5000 and observe what the program prints as output.

---

> an example program assigning a variable data type as `char`, with 5000 in the variable. It is actually a string, 5000 long. Example: (char rating[5000];).

In case you didn't know, a [string](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) is an array of `char` (i.e. characters). `char rating[5000]`is declaring a string data type. It defines `rating` as a string of 5000 `char`s, that is, a string 5000 characters long. **However, it is not initializing `rating` with the value 5000.** Wrong interpretation: `char rating='5000'` **Rather, it is declaring the size of `rating` to be `5000`.**

---

> I thought char could only hold the ascii set or the numerical value.

Yes, you are right about the ascii part. A char variable can hold *any one* ascii value at any time. Letters, digits, and symbols altogether form the ascii set. But, numerical values don't fall into this category. Numerical value is the magnitude, which isn't necessarily made of only one digit. **Digits** (i.e. numerals from 0 to 9) is the right term for it.

---

To sum up, `char` is a data type which can store the value of **a letter / alphabet** or **a digit / number**. A **string** is a group of `char`. '*a*' or '*1*' can be a `char` data, but a *phrase* or a *sentence* can't. To store a group of characters into a variable, use string. Remember these simple facts to make your life easy.